# Inequality $\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1}+\frac{c}{c^2+1} \leq \frac{9}{10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing

Prove that if $a,b,c \geq -\frac34$ and $a+b+c=1$ then inequality $\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1}+\frac{c}{c^2+1} \leq \frac{9}{10}$ holds.

I've been struggling for proving this inequality for quite long time, could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all $x \geqslant -\frac{3}{4},$ we have
$$\frac{x}{x^2+1} \leqslant \frac{18}{25} \cdot x+\frac{3}{50}\Leftrightarrow  \frac{(4x+3)(3x-1)^2}{50(x^2+1)} \geqslant 0 \quad (\text{true}).$$
Therefore
$$\frac{a}{a^2+1}+\frac{b}{b^2+1}+\frac{c}{c^2+1} \leqslant \frac{18}{25}(a+b+c)+ 3 \cdot \frac{3}{50} = \frac{9}{10}.$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got $$\frac{x}{x^2+1} \leqslant \frac{18}{25} \cdot x+\frac{3}{50}$$? I can do it by finding the point (1/3, 3/10) where a line through (-3/4, -12/25) is tangent to $y=x/(x^2+1)$, but that involves solving a couple of quadratics. Is there an easier way?

Comment: @PM2Ring You can see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2131158p15577069)

Comment: Thanks. But it's not clear to me why you set $x_0=1/3$. Is it because the maximum occurs when $a=b=c=1/3$ (and $3\frac{1/3}{1+1/3^2}$ happens to be the maximum given in the question)?

Comment: FWIW, I managed to eliminate those quadratics I mentioned earlier, by dividing out the double root at the tangent point, but it still requires several lines of tedious algebra. ;) I think using partial derivatives is easier...